# Parsing a JSON string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I encountered a weird behaviour of JSON.parse method in javscript.

If you pass it a string in quotes like - "\"I am a random string\""

Instead of throwing an error it will parse the string and return the same

```js
var a = '"I am a random string"';

var b = JSON.parse(a); // no error, parsing is successful

console.log(b); // output "I am a random string"
```

I am wondering what could be the cause of this? Is a string in quotes considered a valid JSON object?

Comment: That's how you encode a string in JSON, yes. From http://www.json.org/: *A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes*

Comment: It's not an object but a *string*. `"foo bar"` is how strings are encoded in JSON. There doesn't have to be an object or array at the top level. Any value is fine. `JSON.parse('null')`, `JSON.parse('true')`, etc are all valid too.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as a JSON object. Your variable `a` contains a string, which, if interpreted in JSON format, is a valid string. Now if you try `var a = "I am a random string"; var b = JSON.parse(a);`, you'll get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JSON Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), a JSON text is any serialized *value*. Any of the following value types is valid JSON:

- Objects (`{ }`)
- Arrays (`[ ]`)
- Strings (`"a"`)
- Numbers (`1`)
- `true`, `false` and `null`

Quoting directly from the grammar in the spec:

```
  value = false / null / true / object / array / number / string
```

`JSON.parse()` can deserialize any kind of value listed above, not just Objects.